# Se me guarda en la BBDD siempre el primer valor del selector. C#, ASP, MYSQL

Tags: c#, mysql, select, asp, dropdownlist

He hecho un select para que luego guarde ese valor en la base de datos. El select se llena mediante una consulta de la base de datos. Hasta ahí todo correcto. El problema llega cuando intento guardar el select en la base de datos. Siempre se me guarda el primer valor seleccione lo que seleccione.

El desplegable es el siguiente:

```
                         <div class="row row-condensed space-4">
                <span class="text-right col-sm-3">Anuncio</span>
                            <div class="col-sm-9"> 
                                <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlAnuncioNoticia" runat="server"></asp:DropDownList>
                            </div>
                        </div>
```

Lo lleno así:

```
   string cadConexion = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["gestionTienda"].ConnectionString;
    MySqlConnection conexion = new MySqlConnection(cadConexion);
    MySqlCommand comando = new MySqlCommand("select nombre from anuncios where bloque= 'PublicidadNoticia' and empresa=@Codigo", conexion);
    comando.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Codigo", club_activo.Codigo);
    MySqlDataAdapter da1 = new MySqlDataAdapter(comando);

    DataSet ds = new DataSet();
    da1.Fill(ds);
    ddlAnuncioNoticia.DataSource = ds;
    ddlAnuncioNoticia.DataTextField = "nombre";
    ddlAnuncioNoticia.DataValueField = "nombre";
    ddlAnuncioNoticia.DataBind();
```

Y para guardarlo en la base de datos hago lo siguiente:

```
  ddlAnuncioNoticia.SelectedValue= actual.Anuncio;
  actual.Anuncio = ddlAnuncioNoticia.SelectedValue;
```

Donde actual.Anuncio es la función donde guarda el valor en el campo correspondiente, que esto lo hace bien, pero no guarda el valor seleccionado.

Muchas gracias de antemano.

Comment: Le tienes puesto un autopostback si no ese valor nunca lo podras obtener

Comment: Si le pongo autopostback siempre se refrescaría el primer valor no? No lo tengo puesto y me saca siempre el mismo valor pese a que haya otro seleccionado.

Comment: No es que para eso debes de meterlo dentro de un update panel para que aunque haga el postback tu puedas obtener el valor que esta seleccioando, mira este ejemplo https://asp-net-example.blogspot.com/2009/03/how-to-use-dropdownlist-autopostback.html

Comment: He estado mirando eso y haciendolo tal cual, y me sigue guardando el primer valor del desplegable.